# jQuery: if $(this) or another element blurs, then

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, event-handling, element

I want to trigger a function if either the currently active element $(this) or another predefined element (e.g.: div#tooltip) blurs. However so far I've not found out how to do this. I've tried:

```
$(this).add('div#tooltip').live('blur', function(){
    $('div#tooltip').hide();
});
```

Imagine that $(this) would be an input field, for example, and the predefined second element would be a tooltip div and that I would want the tooltip to hide if one of those blurs.

**EDIT**:
The div#tooltip contains an anchor, which should not make the div#tooltip hide if it's being clicked.

**EDIT 2**:
Okay, here is a more accurate explanation of my problem. I've got the $.fn.tooltip function which I apply to various text-inputs which have variable class names and id's. Therefore, this input can only be referred to as *$(this)* within the function.
Secondly I have the tooltip div, which is created by the function. This div goes by the ID #tooltip. This tooltip / div can contain some other elements such as anchors.
The tooltip is shown automatically when the input-field (this) is clicked. Once it's closed it won't be shown again, even if the input-field will be focused again.

What I'm trying to do is:

> The tooltip must be removed when the text-input loses it's focus
>   *EXCEPT* if the cursor is within the tooltip / div or if an element within this div is being clicked.

Anyone?

Comment: I don't think the `blur` event is defined for divs. Also, you can just use the id in your jQuery selector, you don't need `div#tooltip`, just `tooltip`. You also may want to post the function that surrounds this code because we have no idea what `this` is even pointing to.

Comment: Correct, divs do not fire onfocusout.  You can capture a click on the div, then watch for a click somewhere else on the doc to simulate blur.

Answer (score 1):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uu3zX/7/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="with-tooltip">
<span class="tooltip">?<a style="display:none" href="#">The tip</a></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.with-tooltip').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).next().children().show();
});

$('.with-tooltip').on('blur', function(){
    $(this).next().children().hide();
});

$('.tooltip').hover(
    function(){
       $(this).children().show();
    },
    function(){
       $(this).children().hide();
    }
);
```

**UPDATE**
Added alternative solution to fit OP requriment to use `this`

Comment: Notice Void's use of on().  It's the preferred way of adding an event handler to an element as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: I would remove the 'blur' and just use 'mouseout' for the first `on`. Keeping it can cause unexpected results. For instance: click inside the input, and then try to click on the tooltip -- the 'blur' fires before the 'focus' does and the tooltip vanishes.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that i can't know '#the-input', because it's depending from the element the function is applied to - in other words, I must use $(this).

Comment: Please take a look at my second update within my original question post

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from IntoTheVoid's fiddle: You should wrap the input and the tooltip in a container div (or some other container element) to do this in one line:

```
$('.tooltip, input').on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.tooltip').hide();
}).on('focus mouseover', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.tooltip').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/uu3zX/5/